# Javascript: Detect scoll and scrolling offset without displaying scrollbars

Tags: javascript, css

I have a coverflow component https://github.com/meghprkh/js-coverflow and a react wrapper around it https://github.com/meghprkh/react-coverflow2 . Now for the coverflow component I need to detect middle mouse button scroll and its intensity but dont have to display scrollbars. How do I do it? Any idea?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel

Comment: @pawel Thanks. mostly this is what I needed. Convert  to answer and I will mark it correct